# Unable to load Static files using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Tried loading static files: CSS, Javascript using django static tag
None of the Javascripts is working, and most of the css are also not loaded

Error for Javascript(***for all JS***):

> The script from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/jquery.min.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

***Django version: - 3.0.1***

My files and code:

> Base.html>>

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static 'animate.css' %}>
<script src="{% static 'jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

> settings.py>>

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")
```

I am not using any virtual environment.

My project folder tree.
[My project Folder and sub directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b8tx.png)

Comment: You have to add your `static url` in project `urls.py` file.

Comment: have to run `python manage.py collectstatic` command.

Comment: I did run collectstatic

Comment: @mohammedwazeem i am new to django can you ellaborate on adding url to urls.py

Comment: @Ritvik I can't see anything wrong with what you show in your question. All your settings are correct for the folder structure you have. That is, assuming you're running locally with `runserver`. However, do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` included in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: The error you see indicates that your static settings are actually correct since the file is loaded. What OS are you on? It seems it doesn't guess the mime types correctly. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) for an explanation.

Comment: Well even though my problem is solved here are the answers to your question:
1- Yes I have `django.contrib.staticfile` included in `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2- Windows is my OS
@dirkgroten

Comment: In a python shell, try `import mimetypes` then `mimetypes.guess_type("jquery.min.js")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your static files in your `my_app/static/` (rather than creating another my_app subdirectory),  where my_app is an app folder inside the main **project** folder. also create a folder with name same as that of your app name inside `static folder` and place your `static files` there. which would properly  distinguish between your `static files`. 
so your final app directory structure look like

```
my_app/
|____static/
     |____my_app/
          |____css/
          |        # your css files
          |____js/
          |        # js files
          |___images/
                   # your image files
```

and update your base.html with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'my_app/css/main.css' %}" />
```

Hopefully that works.

Comment: NameError: name 'static' is not defined

Comment: this is what i am encountering on running server after running collectstatic

Comment: Import these  modules in your project urls.py file                                                `from django.conf import settings`
`from django.conf.urls.static import static`

Comment: Thanks a lot most of the js are loading and working fine but still ther are few with same error other than that no my templates other than base.html which are called using **{% block content %}** are not working

Comment: Check which  `static` files are showing `404 NotFound` in your `dev server` Then you will understand where the server looks for that particular static files. And place your files properly which I have shown in the dir structure. Remember when you change your file path don't forget to change that in the html file for eg: `href="{% static 'my_app/css/main.css' %}"`

Comment: I did made the changes you said.

There is no error regaring any html template file and also **view page source** displays the html content called through ** {% block content %} **

are you on telegram: @Ritvik98

Comment: whats your fb handle

Comment: "you have to add your static url in your project's urls.py" is **not correct**. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) where it says "If you use django.contrib.staticfiles as explained above, runserver will do this automatically when DEBUG is set to True". Also you should **never** add the static urls in production so even if you don't use django.contrib.staticfiles, at least wrap it in a `if settings.DEBUG`.

Comment: Also you should probably mention that `my_app` is an app folder **inside** the main project folder (i.e. `my_app` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`). You could also have a `static` folder inside your main project folder (at the same level as `my_app` and `manage.py`) but then you need to add it to `STATICFILES_DIRS` as OP has done.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yup your are right. Adding static urls in project urls.py file is not suitable for production use .I have updated the answer. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the STATIC_ROOT.
Hopefully that works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).