# How can i deal wth static and media files in django without creating a virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, web, django-settings

I want to use pictures in my application, and in the video I am following he used a virtual environment that I don't know how to create.

Should i create a virtual environment ? If so , how to ?

If not ,
how can I use pictures without creating a virtual environment ?, and what are the settings I have to do in the settings.py and urls.py files?

***setting.py***

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'd0cn(*@vl*liejsapzk2yhoo!$iorw9-hx-43)%mi0g_rf#m$l'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'custom.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'custom.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("",include('posts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns == static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root= settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns == static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please tell us what your doing and what error you are seeing. The part of your question under "**cmd**" isn't clear at all.

Comment: Django is quite extensively documented so I suggest you take time browsing the doc. And no, you don't need a virtualenv to handle media or static files - but you should still use one anyway (it's very easy and avoids a lor of issues)

Comment: It's good practice to set `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to locations **outside of your code repository** to start with. Try `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'))` and `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../media'))`. But these settings are **not required** for development (they only get used when you deploy and run `collectstatic`)

Comment: @dirkgroten i fixed the text, now there is no cmd error

Comment: @AbbasMed but you're not telling us what the issue is. When you say you want to "use pictures" do you mean static files or do you mean user-uploaded media? And what's the problem with your current code? Some error? If so, which?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Django and I am not using a virtual environment so that makes it clear that it is not necessary to use a virtual environment to run a Django application. However, using virtual environment is a good practice.

Coming to setting up Django without any virtual environment:
The only thing you need is to install Django on your PC

> Adding Media and Static files:

I too had issues handling static files in the beginning. I am sharing what I have learned and the method that has worked for me.

> settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "blog/static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "blog/assets")
```

and I suppose you just has to copy above lines with ** STATIC ** replaced with ** MEDIA ** for media files

> urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('test/', user_views.register, name='test'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Do not forget to add ** + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) ** this mistake is usual.

urls.py is the file inside your main django project

Comment: should i create the  static and assets files?

Comment: This is not really a correct answer. First, you don't need to add `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, ...)`. Django `runserver` will find any static assets in your `static` folders in all your apps and in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Second, `MEDIA` is different than static. So it's not just a matter of replacing `STATIC` with `MEDIA`. Third, you should **only** add `+static` to your urls for development and therefore wrap this in `if settings.DEBUG`. You don't want that after you deploy.

Comment: Yes , If you are not using a virtual environment  you need to create a static folder inside your django application folder and inside static folder you need to create another folder with the same name as your application folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478796/10299440
Refer to above link this is the answer on my post that worked

Comment: Well I don't know how are you using Django application but when I created applications using Django it didn't read any of my static files without adding **static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)**

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). "If you use django.contrib.staticfiles as explained above, runserver will do this automatically when DEBUG is set to True."

Comment: @Ritvik also if `blog` is an app inside your project (that you added to `INSTALLED_APPS`), you don't need to add `blog/static` to your `STATICFILES_DIRS` because Django always knows how to find static folders inside all your apps. In addition, your `STATIC_ROOT` setting is bad practice because it points to a folder **inside your code repository**. This setting is only used by `collectstatic` (which you run after you deploy) and tells Django to copy all the static assets to this folder. This should really be a path **outside your project**. Or eventually a 3rd party cloud storage service.

Comment: okk, now I understand the article you suggested says so only if my static files are placed inside a static folder which is inside my django project folder while if I create an application and separate my static files by placing them inside my application folder then the method do not work and then i ahd to add the paths and url using the above method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205158/discussion-between-ritvik-and-dirkgroten).